# Setup MongoDB on Apache

Tags: apache, mongodb

Is it possible to setup MongoDB on Apache? How to do this? 
I have installed Apache on 127.0.0.1:8000 and MongoDb on 127.0.0.1:27017.Does it mean, that they are placed on different servers?
But how to install MongoDb on Apache, I don't know

Comment: You don't "set up MongoDB on Apache". They are both server software. You set them up on the same machine.

Comment: Understand. Mongo has its own server. But is it possible to place Mongo (without its own server) on Apache?

Comment: MongoDB is a standalone database server. They both operate independently and may be either setup on the same machine or different ones.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is a database server which is hosted on localhost:27017,
Apache is a HTTP server which in your case is hosted on localhost:8000. Both are different servers for different purposes. You cannot put a server on top of the other!

As for example, MySQL is a server running on 3306 port. Apache has a plugin to connect with it, not that MySQL runs on Apache.

Comment: Thank you very much! The topic can be closed.